# Cannot do mysql with docker laravel

Tags: mysql

When I run php artisan migrate with the container started with docker, the following error occurs. Is it the root@xxxxxx:/#php artisan migrate that migrates with the container started, or is it $php artisan migrate in another terminal? The latter is done.

```
      Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ogp and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=ogp", "root", "pass", [])
```

```
    #docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: >
      --character-set-server=utf8mb4
      --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
      --general-log=true
      --general-log-file=/var/log/mysql/general.log
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=ogp
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_USER=default
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - TZ=Asia/Tokyo
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

```
#.env
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ogp
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

```
#database.php
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant privileges to your db user

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ogp.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```